# Is my PCB Design of Microcontroller board ready for printing?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I am building a Atmega328p chip based Microcontroller board similar to Arduino. I have prepared the Schematic and PCB design in Easyeda.

But, as I have less experience in designing these, I am quite confused if it's ready now. As there is no good printing service in my locality, there is a high shipping charge for me. So, I want to be sure as much as possible about its functionality before I place order.

My designs: [https://easyeda.com/editor#id=059e74e15b8943869f40f068905ce13b|ce80afceb054496b9520f2cebb2ee0a2](https://easyeda.com/editor#id=059e74e15b8943869f40f068905ce13b%7Cce80afceb054496b9520f2cebb2ee0a2)

(Easyeda requires login probably, But here is my schematic. But the PCB can't be understood from images, I guess)
[image]

Can you help me to understand if there is any mistake here? If this is not the right place to ask for it, where can I get help about designs?

Thanks

EDIT:
Really appreciate your comments and answers guys. These are what you all pointed out -

1. Reverse polarity of LEDs
2. TX RX pins need to be switched
3. Voltage divider won't work, it needs a voltage regulator
4. No resistor needed from regulator to ground
5. No capacitor in series needed in DTR?
6. Inappropriate voltage regulation
7. TVS array to protect CH340 ic
8. Two 1k resistors in series from CH340 to header pins instead of taking from atmega

Are there any mistakes remaining?

Comment: there is nothing under your link

Comment: I can't see any designs there, and I don't know what Easyeda is or how to use it. Please post your actual designs here as images.

Comment: @Ilya I have adeed the schematic. But, how can I show the pcb in images?

Comment: Your TX/RX are flipped to start with. TX on one side goes to RX on another side

Comment: Are you powering it from USB? D1 will drop the voltage. 3v3 comes from a resistor divider, so you can't really power much with P3 connector, or what is the purpose of that? If you have problems in programming, it might be due to 10 k pull up and only 10 n series cap from CH340.

Comment: There are some problems in the schematic that need to be addressed before considering the PCB, the most obvious being the lack of decoupling capacitors, the resistor in the ground-line of the voltage regulator, the capacitor in series with the DTR line, and the reverse polarity of LEDs 2 & 3. I suggest you do a thorough design check before laying out the PCB., or maybe just copy an existing working design, with a few bits added to customise it - that is much safer than creating something from scratch.

Comment: Querying design feedback is a very open-ended question. There is no right or wrong answer really, everything can always be done better or simpler and it depends what you want from the circuit. But yes there are definite mistakes and bad decisions. Leds are upside down. And the AMS1117 needs more than 5V in to make 5V out, so you never get 5V out, the output wil always be below 5V and out of regulation. And what is the purpose of R1 on regulator ground pin, it makes no sense. What frequency is X1?

Comment: @jayben thanks for pointing out the mistakes. I really appreciate it. I actually followed designs made by people. And added them together with some customizations.

Comment: @Justme Thanks! Yes, I understand that. I am checking for mistakes mainly. I followed a design made by another guy for the resistor on ground. I didn't quite get it as well. Should I remove it? X1 is 20mhz. But, Why will the AMS1117 get less than 5v?

Comment: USB is 5V. You have a diode in series so it will drop 0.7V before the regulator. Regulator will not output even 4.5V, which is required for 16 MHz operation. The ATMega328P is not even rated for 20 MHz so it can't work with 20 MHz crystal.

Comment: Using 1K resistors in series with tx/rx allows you to use these pins without interfering with ch340. In current design, the UART is exclusively used for ch340. You can't use the pins or the uart system for another purpose (e.g. a GSM or GPRS module).

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad That's not a mistake though, that's a suggestion for improvement which might be a good one but out of scope. It was only asked if it is ready (no) and if there is any mistakes (yes). These kind of lists never end, nobody can define when the design is good enough to be finished.

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad But how will it convert usb to serial then? 

Comment: @Justme Got the voltage part. But it's not true that atmega328p can't work with 20mhz. Those have max 20mhz capability. (i have checked datasheet)

Comment: I have also checked the ATMega328P datasheet twice already and it's still 16 MHz. Either you made a mistake or it is some other part than ATMega328P. Please link to datasheet.

Comment: You are checking an older model then. I am using atmega328p-mu: https://octopart.com/atmega328p-mu-microchip-77760221

Comment: I would recommend adding a TVS array to the USB port for ESD protection. Since you're using EasyEDA I guess you're manufacturing with JLC, so I'd recommend the Protek SRV05-4 (C85364). Attach VBUS to REF, GND to GND, and D+/D- to any of the four IO pins. Place it physically close to the USB port. It's a $0.14 part that might save you killing your CH340 by accident.

Comment: Your top copper fill is next to useless. Having open ended stubs is bad juju. Concentrate on having an uninterrupted copper fill for 0V on the bottom layer.

Comment: @Abrar Yes it still can use the USB-UART. look at arduino schematics. they use a similar approach.

Comment: @Polynomial Thanks for the suggestion! It's a really good one :D

Comment: @Kartman can you please explain that? I could not understand what you meant to say

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad got it now. thanks, i will do it :)

Comment: Decoupling capacitors for the Vcc of your micro comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several points:
UART's line must have TX pin on one side and RX pin on another side. You have TX connected to TX and RX connected to RX. It won't work. Swap them (TX to RX, RX to TX).

Your 3.3V Reference provided with 2.2k and 3.3k and LED will actually be around 2V. You have voltage drop on LED that you didn't take into account. Also, you can't power anything from that 3.3V, it's only reference voltage.

What's the point of 1117-5V (U2)? It receives USB 5V and is supposed to output the same 5V?

Comment: I totally forgot about the RX and TX pins. Thanks for pointing out! I indeed forgot about the voltage drop. AMS1117-5V is receiving power from USB which is unregulated power.

Comment: @Abrar since when is USB unregulated power? It's stable 5V. And if you need a 3.3V rail, you need a proper supply for it. Such as 1117 3.3V

Comment: the power will not be supplied from computer always. like when working with arduino, the power is supplied from various sources. that's why it's there

Comment: It will still be regulated 5V

Comment: But how? Arduino boards has a regulatior ic as well. That's what I am following mainly. Besides, I will also put two pins for directly connect power. I think, even if usb doesn't need that, the header pins will need it.

Comment: First of all, any linear regulator has dropout voltage. So output voltage is at least some 0.5V lower (depends very much on regulator, from near 0 to 1.2V or so). And you have a useless diode there. You get 5V to the board via USB, drop it via diode to 4.4V, pass it through the regulator which doesn't do anything and drop it to 4V or even lower. Arduino's USB power goes directly to MCU. The regulator is there to lower barrel jack's 9V (or whatever it is, hence unregulated) to 5V. USB gives stable predictable 5V, hence it is regulated

Comment: @Abrar You might want to examine Arduino schematics to find out how it works if you want to clone it.

Comment: @Ilya got it now. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest:

- decoupling capacitors for the IC's - 10uF and 100nF. Check the datasheets and I'm sure they will suggest suitable values.
- Also, test points (pads on the PCB) - it's always useful when debugging.
- Be sure to route AREF and any other analog signals away from switching nodes to avoid noise.
- If you have any unused inputs on chips that do not have internal pull-up/down resistors (check datasheets), add externally. Floating inputs can be a problem.
- Generally it might be a good idea to add a fuse to your supply lines. Self resettable SMD type are very cheap these days and can save your board
- ESD protection on your USB might be useful. Single package devices are readily available.
- Protecting any inputs with clamp diodes might be a useful addition
- Possibly add some debouncing on your switch
- Your 3.3V that you are generating with the resistor divider cannot be used to power anything (use it as a reference only for high impedance inputs). If you try and source or sink current into the resistor network, the voltage changes.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!